# Injective modules

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $k$-algebra and let $I$ be an injective module。My question is whether $I$ is a direct sum of finite-dimensional injective modules。

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

Let $M$ be any $A$-module. Then its socle is a direct sum of simple modules: $\operatorname{soc}A=\bigoplus_iS_i$.

$A$ is a finite dimensional algebra, so the dual $\mathrm{Hom}_k(A,k)$ of $A$ is a finite dimensional injective into which every simple module embeds. So each $I(S_i)$ is finite-dimensional.

The direct sum $I=\bigoplus_iI(S_i)$ of the injective envelopes of the simples is injective, so the natural inclusion $\operatorname{soc}A\to I$ extends to a map $M\to I$, which it is easy to see is an essential monomorphism, and so $I$ is the injective envelope of $M$.

If $M$ itself is injective, then $M=I=\bigoplus_iI(S_i)$ is a direct sum of finite dimensional injective modules.

Comment: This argument (which I would have rephrased as: if $I$ is injective indecomposable, then its socle is simple) boils down to showing that the injective hull of a simple module is finite-dimensional. How do you see this?

Comment: @YCor $A$ is a finite dimensional algebra, so the dual $\operatorname{Hom}_k(A,k)$ of $A$ is a finite dimensional injective into which every simple module embeds.

Comment: When passing to the dual $A^*:=\hom_k(A,k)$ you switch from left modules to right modules and right modules to left modules. So you maybe want to use the double dual. If $M$ is irreducible then so is $M^*$. Thus there is a surjection $A\twoheadrightarrow M^*$ and thus there is an embedding $M=M^{**}\rightarrowtail A^*$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Do you know if the analogous holds for graded algebras? So if, say, $A$ is graded over $\mathbb{Z}$ (or perhaps a torsion free group, or any abelian group) and $I$ is graded injective, then is $I$ a direct sum of finite dimensional graded injectives?